# How to implement two layout for different screen size in MainActivity

Tags: android, android-layout, fragment, android-screen-support, android-layout-weight

I am following Udacity's course where at last during completion I met with this error.

You can also check the Udacity's code by clicking [here](https://github.com/udacity/Android_Me/blob/TFragments.07-Solution-TwoPaneUI/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/android_me/ui/MainActivity.java)
and my layout files [1](https://github.com/udacity/Android_Me/blob/TFragments.07-Solution-TwoPaneUI/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml) & [2](https://github.com/udacity/Android_Me/blob/TFragments.07-Solution-TwoPaneUI/app/src/main/res/layout-sw600dp/activity_main.xml).

**

> Thanks in advance.

**

```
com.thelazyprogrammer.harshit.mycustomapps.ui.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:29)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6998)
```

This error is pointing to `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

But don't know what is missing.
My code:-

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MasterListFragment.OnImageClickListener
{
    // Variable to store the values of list index of selected image.
    private int headIndex,
    bodyIndex,
    legIndex;

    private boolean mTwoPane;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   /*<---THE ABOVE ERROR POINTING BELOW LINE'S CODE--->*/
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
   /*<------------------------------------------------>*/

        /*Intent intent = new Intent(this, AndroidMeActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);*/

        if(findViewById(R.id.android_me_linear_layout) != null)
        {
            mTwoPane=true;


            // Setting grid view into two columns.
            GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.images_grid_view);
            gridView.setNumColumns(2);

            // Getting rid of the button in the tablet mode.
            Button nextButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next_button);
            nextButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);

if(savedInstanceState!=null)
{
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

    BodyClassFragment headFragment, bodyFragment, legFragment;

    // Creating new head, body, leg.
    headFragment = new BodyClassFragment();
    headFragment.setImageIds(AndroidImageAssets.getHeads());

    bodyFragment = new BodyClassFragment();
    bodyFragment.setImageIds(AndroidImageAssets.getBodies());

    legFragment = new BodyClassFragment();
    legFragment.setImageIds(AndroidImageAssets.getLegs());

    // Adding fragment to it's container.
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.head_container, headFragment)
            .add(R.id.body_container, bodyFragment)
            .add(R.id.leg_container, legFragment)
            .commit();
}
        }
        else
        {
            mTwoPane=false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to learn the basic of display size from [Google Docs.](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes)

Comment: I read this documentation, I got the concept right. But still I am missing something.

Comment: Android loads/parses the XML by choosing it following a simple rule: which "R.layout.xxxxx" to use depends on Display Size and Sdk version you wants to target to. For example you can create "layout-320dp" folder and create the same filename you have in the generic "layout" folder but reserved for those device that has 320dp as resolution. Same thing if you want to use a different layout from Android M: you can create a folder "layout-v23" and create the same filename BUT different content and it will used only starting from Marshmallow (6.x).

Comment: I got all the things what you trying to convey, But where is the solution to my question ? I had done same created folder with same name assigned in MainActivity.

Comment: Why you didn't post the incriminated "R.layout.activity_main"? How can we help you without that specific file that creates all the problems?

Comment: I had provided to the link to the code. 
Anyway. Please find my layout 1 & 2 files in above link.